# How to convert string of words to decimal

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to do some cryptography-related stuff and I want to convert a string "Hello my name is: " into decimal. My idea is to get the ascii values of each letter, convert into binary, concatenate the binaries, convert to decimal. The reason I want to do this is because I'm trying out RSA encryption on strings.

I have written some code but have gotten stuck at converting to decimal because my concatenated binary is a string. I have no idea how to convert it to binary.

```
(* the string *)
string="Hello my name is: ";

(* convert string to ascii *)
ascii=ToCharacterCode[string];
Print[ascii];

(* for loop, every element to binary, concat *)
binConcat="";
For[i=1,i<StringLength[string],i++;
    element=BaseForm[ascii[[i]],2];
    elementStr=ToString[element];
    binConcat=StringJoin[binConcat,elementStr];
    ]
```

Would appreciate if someone could help me. Maybe there is a much more straight forward way to do this as well. I did it in Python and now I would like to do it on Wolfram Engine. Thank you!

Comment: seen [Encrypt](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encrypt.html)  or [StringToByteArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringToByteArray.html) in the docs?

Comment: Other options `FromDigits[ascii]` or `ToString /@ ascii // StringJoin // ToExpression`.

Comment: @kglr Encrypt won't work because I need to know the keys myself. If I use StringToByteArray, I would still need to convert to binary then to decimal right?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I looked up these before but they don't work for me.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi As for FromDigits[ascii], it might work, but it's not converting to the right format. I am not sure how to specify I want a conversion from ascii to decimal.

Comment: For the string "is", what are you expecting the decimal value to be?